# prevent some code to be build on production - angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, lazy-loading, production

Hi I'm working on some company, I build testing module for the developer to help them use the component of the project

However, I prevent this module from being accessed on production.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment.prod';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  ...(environment.production
    ? []
    : [
        {
          path: 'testing',
          loadChildren: () =>
            import('@fnx-nx/front/main-app-testing').then(
              (m) => m.FrontMainAppTestingModule
            ),
        },
      ]),
];
```

In addition to this lazy chunk module not being access on production,
When I run build command with production flag
I want to skip this lazy chunk build.

There is some way that will change the way the build will behave to this need?